# Images appear "washed out" based on background color, using EMGU Camera library

Tags: vb.net, image, image-processing, emgucv

I'm using the [EMGU CV .NET](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) library. I noticed that when I take pictures of anything with color, the colors usually get "washed out" if the background is dark(ish). General rule of thumb I've found is that, the darker the background is, the more washed out the colors are.

Here is how I'm retrieving the image from the camera with EMGU.

```
Dim imgFeed As Bitmap = mCamera.RetrieveBgrFrame.ToBitmap
```

In the images below (cropped out some of the background on both), the left image is on dry white cement and the right image is on wet white cement. You can see the "washed out" color especially on the first tag, which is bright orange duct tape.

[image: Colors on dry white cement]
[image: Colors on wet white cement]

Here is another image, taken on black pavement in the sun, which in reality is much darker than the white cement, but appears similar in color to the background in the wet cement image above.

[image: Gold on pavement]

Is there some sort of auto-balancing that's occurring in the EMGU library? If so, can I stop this from happening? I need to see the colors more clearly than the background. I've read about `_EqualizeHist()` and I implemented it, but that did not help me see the colors any more clearly; adding contrast to the image didn't really help because the colors were already close to white.

### Update

After reading Spark's answer, I found the `SetCaptureProperty()` method. I see that you can disable the auto exposure property by setting the value to 0 as shown below.

```
mCamera.SetCaptureProperty(CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0.0)
```

Sadly though, with the particular camera I'm using, it looks like the driver does not support changing this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with the algorithm. It is the behavior of Auto Exposure (AEC) algorithm running inside camera chip. Try disabling auto exposure control of camera and reduce the manual exposure level.

**Little theory:** Most of the AEC algorithm works with full frame weighted method. So in the sample which you showed for white washed case, the black background occupies more portion of the image, which make AEC algorithm to assume that the image is too dark and hence increase exposure level internally.